# Grouped SKUs vs. Ungrouped SKUs on Product List Page

Tags: e-commerce, conversion

Some e-commerce sites will group similar SKUs together on their product listing page.  For example, Macy's would group the same modeled stand mixer with different colors together and just show different color options within the SKU box:

[image]

Other e-commerce sites will have similar SKUs spread out (ungrouped) on their product listing page.  For example, these same modeled headsets on Amazon:

[image]

**From the UX perspective, which method is better at converting browsers to paying customers?**

Please back up your claim with data or research, thanks.

Comment: Despite the qualifier, it seems like this is a marketing question rather than a UX question.  Even if UX is involved in the explanation, it's marketing data you're asking for (and success in monetising something is by no means the same as having good UX).  There seems to be a prototype marketing SE site here: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/65811/digital-marketing  --that may be more helpful...

Answer (score 1):

From a SEO point of view I would use a separate product page for each color, and distinctly put it in the product descriptions. That way when people are searching for a red mixer, they will find your site. You also have more landing pages you can customize from a SEO standpoint.

From a UX point of view it would definitely depend on the way you present it. If i'm buying a red mixer, I would like to see an image of a red mixer. Not just a green one with "Also in red". What color red? Light, dark? Is just the main color red, or are also the black shades in a different color, etc.

The different colors also need to be grouped together. I hate when I see a product I like, then some other products and then the same product again in a different color. Scrolling through 500 products, that are actually 50 products in 10 colors, is also annoying.

So I guess the best way to go is to use them both. Use a separate page for each products  color, but also show the other available color for each product.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to find out is do some A/B testing on your site.

Comment: -1 for something you could have said in comments.

Comment: My apologies, I'm very new to this site.